# Filtering lambda expression that compares two elements of the same collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, comparison

I was wondering if it is possible to write an expression for a Linq extension (or a custom extension) to filter a collection using a lambda expression that compares two elements of the collection.

In other words, if I have a `List<DateTime>` and some value, `var v = DateTime.Today`, then I am wondering if it is possible to write create a method that will return the first element of the collection that is less than or equal to the value, `current <= v`, with the next element of the collection being greater than or equal to the value, `next >= v`.

*Please note that the above is just an example, and may or may not be the final implementation.*

The following would be a valid solution, were the `.First()` method to accept `Func<DateTime, DateTime, bool>` with the two `DateTime` parameters being consecutive elements of the sequence:

```
dateCollection.First((current, next) => current <= v && next >= v);
```

Please also note that with the example given, a valid workaround could be to use `.OrderBy` and then find the first index that is greater than `d` and subtract `1`. However, this type of comparison is not the only one that I am looking for. I may have a situation in which I am checking a `List<string>` for the first situation where the `current` element starts with the first letter of my value, `v`, and the `next` element ends with the last letter of my value, `v`.

I am looking for something that would be just a few of code. My goal is to find the simplest solution to this possible, so brevity carries a lot of weight.

What I am looking for is something of the form:

```
public static T First (...)
{
    ...
}
```

I believe that this will also require two or more lambda expressions as parameters. One thing that may also provide a good solution is to be able to select into all possible, consecutive pairs of elements of the sequence, and call the `.First()` method on that.

For example:

```
//value 
var v = 5;

//if my collection is the following
List<int> stuff = { a, b, c, d };

//select into consecutive pairs, giving: 
var pairs = ... // { { a, b }, { b, c }, { c, d } };

//then run comparison
pairs.First(p => p[0] <= v && p[1] >= v).Select(p => p[0]);
```

Thanks and happy coding! :)

Comment: Not really sure what you want to return here is my main question? a single DateTime object or more than one?

Comment: " create a method that will return the first element of the collection that is less than or equal to the value"...

Comment: This would have to be multiple lambdas in a single method

Comment: @Ric " with the next element of the collection being greater than or equal to the value "

Comment: still a single object being returned though.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Can you spell out what you expect as a return? you can put a placeholder where you'd like the lambda to be, but we need to know what you expect the lambda to return...

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv - sure, give me a second

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv - I know that is still pretty vague, as the return value would, of course, have to be an anonymous type, but I hope that helps

Comment: I think I might throw a bounty on this when it's eligible

Comment: The return value should be a pair? Since anonymous types can't be returned, and not counting dynamics, would it be ok to return a Tuple<T,T> ? The provided answers could still be used, with a compareto implementation instead of > and <

Comment: @Me.Name - No! Tuple's are great, but I messed up. I'll fix. I meant to only provide an example. I am really looking to knock heads together with everyone to find the best solution, so be creative! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we can create is a `Pairwise` method that can map a sequence of values into a sequence of pairs representing each value and the value that comes before it.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Pairwise<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        T prev = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(prev, iterator.Current);
            prev = iterator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can write out:

```
var item = data.Pairwise()
    .First(pair => pair.Item1 <= v && pair.Item2 >= v)
    .Item1;
```

If this is something you're going to use a fair bit, it may be worth creating a new custom type to replace `Tuple`, so that you can have `Current` and `Next` properties, instead of `Item1` and `Item2`.

Comment: Terrific solution @Servy! Not only does this do exactly what I am looking for, but it also accounts for collections that are not iterable!

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel You mean indexable, not iterable, but yes.

Comment: Hahahaha Yes, I did mean indexable. Iterable would just be silly :P

Answer (score 3):

```
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(3);
    list.Add(2);
    list.Add(8);
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(4);

    var element = list
         .Where((elem, idx) => idx < list.Count-1 && elem<=list[idx+1])
         .FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine(element);
```

rsult: 2

where 'elem' is the current element, and 'idx' is an index of the current element

Comment: This is the `.Where .First` solution that I alluded to in my comments on one of the other answers. Very clean, and effective! Thanks Arie!

Answer (score 1):

Strictly following the description, you could combine linq and list indexes to find the first index that matches your criterium, and returning its element:

```
DateTime d= DateTime.Today;
var res = dateCollection[Enumerable.Range(0, dateCollection.Count - 1).First(i => dateCollection[i] <= d && dateCollection[i + 1] >= d)];
```

Comment: I like it and am upvoting because it is a completely valid solution. However, I was hoping there might be a solution that would only involve a single method that takes one or more lambda expressions.

Comment: that's actually better than mine becuase of the Range option... :)

Comment: I believe that the `Range` call isn't actually necessary. Unless I'm mistaken, you could use the built-in indexer. If there isn't one, then doing `.Where((element, i) => ...).First()` would be the same. Still a good solution though, which is why I upvoted ;)

Comment: This assumes that the collection is indexable, which if its an arbitrary `IEnumerable`, it may not be.

Comment: @Servy yep, but the original example did say *List*<datetime>

Comment: Sorry about that Me.Name - I fixed that bug in my post ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you want to return here is my main question, but to take your example and put it into a LINQ statement, it would be like this:

```
DateTime? Firstmatch = dateCollection.DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault(a => a <= d && ((dateCollection.IndexOf(a) + 1) < (dateCollection.Count) && dateCollection[dateCollection.IndexOf(a) + 1] >= d));
```

Comment: Pretty similar to @Me.Name's solution, but I like the elimination of the call to `.Range()`

Answer (score 0):

Servy's answer can be handled without an extension method:

```
var first = items
  .Select((current, index) => index > 0 ? new { Prev = items.ElementAt(index-1), Current = current } : null)
  .First(pair => pair != null && pair.Prev <= v && pair.Current >= v)
  .Prev;
```

Comment: Casey - Thanks for your answer. However, @Servy's answer provides support for those collections that may not be indexable, which is why he added an extension method. Yours is not a bad solution, however ;) +1

Comment: What do you mean by not 'indexable'? Is the .Select method I used not supported by all IEnumerable<T> regardless of T?

Comment: This is an O(n^2) operation.  Mine is an O(n) operation.  `ElementAt` is an O(n) operation on `IEnumerable`, so calling it in a loop to get the previous item is a *really* bad idea.  You'd be better of materializing the query into a list and then using one of the other solutions that relies on the data source having an indexer than using this solution.

Comment: OK - I see what you are saying. That said, I don't know that you can say it is an O(n^2) operation though - wouldn't it really depend on whether or not the underlying enumerable implemented IList<T>?